# Loopback address as Facebook redirect url

Tags: facebook-graph-api, redirect

I have been trying to integrate Facebook, Youtube and Dailymotion and have been successful to some extent. The only problem I am facing is Dailymotion doesnt accept 'localhost' as the redirect url, so I need to put the loopback address (127.0.0.1). While for Facebook,I can put the loopback address in the "Site URL" field, however then I cannot put the same in "App Domains" field without which it doesnt work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So this is for local developing purposes? Just use any domain name (made up or real), and set it to point to your system’s IP in your local DNS configuration (f.e. via `hosts` file) – that’s enough to test any stuff like login etc. that does not require Facebook to actually connect to your server.

Comment: Also, why do the redirect URLs for Facebook and Dailymotion need to be the same?